# ios stock edit screen

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

When you open a picture in your photo album and you select a picture there is an edit button top right which opens up auto enhance/red eye and crop features.  Is there a way to get this view/screen in iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `UIImagePickerController` to allow the user to select images from their library you can set its `allowsEditing` property to yes. I think this only allows the cropping feature though, not the red-eye. If you want a red-eye feature you'd have to do it yourself, consider [Core Image auto adjustment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH11-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

As @Wain stated, with `UIImagePickerController` you can't do much with the `allowsEditing` set to `YES` other than crop/resize.

See [Core Image Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) for more information on editing photos.

Additionally, there are third-party libraries and SDK's that'll allow you to edit the image more thoroughly.

AviarySDK is easy to set up and use in your apps.  You can download their sample app for free in the app store if you want to see what it can do.  Check it out here: http://aviary.com/